# Google.Apis.Auth version mismatch between the installed versions. C# Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-iam

Error : Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.46.0.0, Culture=neutral, publickeytoken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference (Exception fron HRESULT:0x80131040)

Facing this error only when we code is deployed to VM. In local machine there is no error. Installed Version of Google.Api.Auth is 1.58.0.0 upon looking in the DLL in packages folder.

.NET Framework - 4.8

Code :

```
using Google.Cloud.Iam.Credentials.V1;
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc.Core.Logging;

public string SignedJwt()
{
     GrpcEnviornment.SetLogger(new ConsoleLogger());

     string token = string.Empty;
     try
     {
        IAMCredentialsClient iamCredentialsClient = IAMCredentialsClient.Create();
      
        JsonPayload payload = new JsonPayload
        {
             AUD = uri,
             ISS = serviceAccount,
             SUB = serviceAccount,
             IAT = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
             EXP = DataTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10).ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
         };
     
         var response = iamCredentialsClient.SignJwt("projects/-/serviceAccounts/serviceAccount");

         token = response.SignedJwt;

     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     { 

     }

     return token;

}
```